# Does each vhost need a different socket?

Tags: nginx

I have just started using nginx so I'm a bit confused with the socket setting. It seems like I have to set listen to /var/run/php5-fpm.sock for example. But if I have multiple sites running on the same server do I have to have different socket for each one? Say /var/run/site1.sock and /var/run/site2.sock?

Sorry for asking such question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can handle all of your servers (vhosts in Apache terms) with a single php-fpm socket. It might be better to have more than one socket for performance reasons, if you don't or can't optimize the socket handling of your operating system or if your hardware simply can handle much more. But for normal use cases a single socket should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need different sockets for each virtual host.

You *do*, however, need different sockets for distinct php-fpm pools.

If you're running all your virtual hosts in the same php-fpm pool, then you only need a single socket. However, if you move some of them into a different pool, that pool is a completely separate process group and needs a different socket.

Comment: I see, does putting them under the same pool meaning they will run with the user, group and chroot and thus cause security concern?

Comment: Each pool runs as its own user and environment. Whether that's a security concern depends on external factors.